# I have two error : No visible @interface for 'UIWebview'

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have two error :No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'highlightAllOccurencesOfString:'

another one:No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'removeAllHighlights'
Please someone help me.

WBSecondViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @interface WBSecondViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>{
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@property(copy) NSArray *menuItems;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *webToolBar;
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)foward:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender;
@end
```

WBSecondViewController.m

```
#import "WBSecondViewController.h"
#import "Word.h"
#import "WordController.h"
#import "AddWordController.h"
#import "WBAppDelegate.h"
#import "WBFirstViewController.h"
#import "SearchWebView.h"

@interface WBSecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation WBSecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Second", @"Second");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.jp"];
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]];
}
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{

[_webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"cat"];
}

-(IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender{

[_webView removeAllHighlights];

}
```

SearchWebView.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SearchWebView : UIWebView

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str;
- (void)removeAllHighlights;

@end
```

SearchWebView.m

```
#import "SearchWebView.h"

@implementation SearchWebView

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];

NSString *startSearch = [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('%@')",str];
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

NSString *result = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_SearchResultCount"];
return [result integerValue];
}

- (void)removeAllHighlights
{
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights()"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U have subclassed uiwebview and called it SearchWebView but then when you create an instance of web view in your wbsecondviewcontroller, you use a regular web view instead of the subclass that you created and the regular web view does not have the two extra methods that you defined for that custom one.  Above @interface in the wbsecondviewcontroller.h do `@class SearchWebView`. Then where you declare the property UiWebView, declare it as a SearchWebView instead.  In the .m file of the wbsecondviewcontroller do `#import "SearchWebView.h"`

Comment: Also: Replace `#import <Foundation/Foundation>` with `#import <UIKit/UIKit>` in `SearchWebView.h`

Comment: Thanks anser this.I tried add @class SearchWebView and so on.Then my program's error disappeared.But now,It have new error.I do this program.Then get that error message from Xcode.2012-12-02 00:14:24.678 WordBook[6721:c07] -[UIWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7167520
2012-12-02 00:14:24.678 WordBook[6721:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7167520'

Comment: @user, you appear to have completely ignored this answers suggestions, if you are still getting the same result.

Comment: I think I don't ignored answers suggestions.I'm not get same result.I just have new error.What can I do?

Comment: You have to read up on how subclassing works and how to use it properly or you will keep getting errors like this.  Look at every place where you call highlightAllOccurancesOfString and make sure that the object is of type SearchWebView instead of Uiwebview.  If in the .h or .m file you have something like uiwebview *someView, you can not send it highlightAllOccurancesOfString. It must be changed to SearchWebView *someview.  Don't forget to accept my answer if it fixed the original problem you were looking for so other people who have the same problem know that it worked.