# Why I get this error? At Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have two error : No visible @interface for ‘UIWebview’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660379/i-have-two-error-no-visible-interface-for-uiwebview)

Why I get this error at Xcode. Error is that:No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'highlightAllOccurencesOfString:' and No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'removeAllHighlights'. Where are wrong?

WBSecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WBSecondViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>{}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *webToolBar;

- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender;

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str;
- (void)removeAllHighlights;

@end
```

WBSecondViewController.m

```
#import "WBSecondViewController.h"

@interface WBSecondViewController ()
@end

@implementation WBSecondViewController

-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"highlighttes");
[_webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"不明"];
}

-(IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender{
[_webView removeAllHighlights];
}

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];

NSString *startSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('%@')",str];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

NSString *result = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_SearchResultCount"];
return [result integerValue];
}

- (void)removeAllHighlights
{
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights()"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question again just because you didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are wrong,

```
[_webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"不明"];
[_webView removeAllHighlights];
```

It should be,

```
[self highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"不明"];
[self removeAllHighlights];
```

You are trying to call `highlightAllOccurencesOfString` and `removeAllHighlights` which are defined in `WBSecondViewController`'s `@interface` but on `UIWebview` objects. Compiler is not able to find it in `UIWebView` class `@interface` and hence the error message as `No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector ...`

Answer (score 1):

`highlightAllOccurencesOfString` and `removeAllHighlights` are method defined in your `WBSecondViewController`, while you are attempting to call them on a `UIWebView` object. Try with this:

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{
   NSLog(@"highlighttes");
   [self highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"不明"];
}

-(IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender{
   [self removeAllHighlights];
}
```

This will at least compile.